# Facebook share button not loading with Rails turbolinks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook

I was following Facebook general guidlines to include Share button (Social Plugin)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

_social.html.erb

```
<div id="fb-root"><div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.example.com" data-layout="button_count"></div></div>
```

fb_share.js

```
var fb_share;
fb_share = function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');

$(document).ready(fb_share);
$(document).on('page:load', fb_share)
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

The button renders on first page load, works correctly also. But is not rendered when navigating to next page and back.

If I include fb_share.js file in application.js file (before turbolinks) it doesn't show up at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Facebook JS SDK only goes through the HTML document *once* upon initialization, to look for elements to replace with the FB social plugins.

And trying to embed the JS SDK again, as you are trying by calling `fb_share`, is useless – because that code is specifically written to *not* embed it again, if it has been embedded already.

The *correct* way to get the SDK to parse the document again for content added only later on, is to call [FB.XFBML.parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/).

Answer (score 6):

For Turbolinks 5, this is the only thing that worked for me: https://gist.github.com/6temes/52648dc6b3adbbf05da3942794b97a00

```
// FacebookSDK
// https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); // Replace 'facebook-jssdk' with your page id.

// Compatibility with Turbolinks 5
(function($) {
  var fbRoot;

  function saveFacebookRoot() {
    if ($('#fb-root').length) {
      fbRoot = $('#fb-root').detach();
    }
  };

  function restoreFacebookRoot() {
    if (fbRoot != null) {
      if ($('#fb-root').length) {
        $('#fb-root').replaceWith(fbRoot);
      } else {
        $('body').append(fbRoot);
      }
    }

    if (typeof FB !== "undefined" && FB !== null) { // Instance of FacebookSDK
      FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
  };

  document.addEventListener('turbolinks:request-start', saveFacebookRoot)
  document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', restoreFacebookRoot)
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2):

For TurboLinks 5 this worked for me!

It is necessary to add `data-turbolinks-permanent` to the fb-root element!

```
<div id="fb-root" data-turbolinks-permanent></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  if(window.FB) {
    FB.XFBML.parse();
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! annotating `fb-root` element with `data-turbolinks-permanent` to make the element permanent and the `EventListener` for `XFBMLParse` worked for me. Here's some documentation on "Persisting Elements Across Page Loads" https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#persisting-elements-across-page-loads